# Область видимости переменной или вывод значения вне функции

Tags: переменные, javascript, функции

Подскажите, вот есть такая функция kapital, она считает цифры, и всё хорошо, но вот в конце этой функции написано, что она должна выводить результат в html, но она этого как раз и не делает, но при этом, когда вставляю переменную summ в конце, она прекрасно выводит результат. Почему функция не выводит html?

```
        else if (allsrok == 91) {
                    var summa;
        var predsumma;                                                  
        var postsum;
            function kapital(){
            predsumma = ( 1 + (9.6 * 31) / (100 * 365));
            postsum = Math.pow( predsumma , 3 );
            summa = allsum *  postsum;
            container.innerHTML = "Срочный накопительный с капитализацией" + summa
            };  
         prevrez = allsum/100*9.8; rezultat = prevrez/12 * 3; // Срочный
         prevrezd = allsum/100*9.7; rezultatd = prevrezd/12 * 3; // Срочный с довлажением
//       prevrezn = allsum/100*9.6; rezultatn = prevrez/12 * 3; // Срочный накопительный
         kapital();
            container.innerHTML = "На срок 91 " + '<br>' +  rezultat + " Рублей" + '<br>' + "Срочный с довлажением " + rezultatd + " Рублей"+'<br>' + summa //allsum
        }
```

Comment: Что такое container? Где она берется? Если Вы хотите, чтобы мы Вам подсказали, напишите сюда весь код.

Comment: мне кажется вне ф-ции переменная someware не будет видна вообще

Comment: @mountpoint, container.innerHTML = - это для вывода htl кода  
<div id="container"></div>

Comment: на самом деле функция все выводит, но вы следующей строкой переписываете ее вывод `container.innerHTML = "На срок 91 " + '<br>' +  rezultat ....`

Answer (score 1):

Для размышления, если внутри функции написать var somevar, то внутри этой функции соответственно создастся новая переменная с именем somevar. Если внутри функции написать somevar = 10, то переменная (в глобальной области или на уровень выше) с именем somevar будет переопределена (значение поменяется) и будет равной 10.

Answer (score 0):

Проверяйте в консоли, какие ошибки выдает ваш скрипт.

У вас нет переменной allsum.

Посмотрите [ссылку](http://jsfiddle.net/pcrqsych/).

Comment: Она есть, просто вынесена за пределы ифа, у меня вопрос исключително в том почему ф-ция не выводи хтмл, думал может логическое какое объяснение....